# Dependency 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.15' not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

На одном компьютере все проекты работают нормально, а ну другом в каждом ошибки в pom.xml файле. Я уже пробовал и IntelliJ Idea переустановить и везде в настройках выстаивить по умолчанию Java 15 (1.8). Ничего не помогает. Ни один проект не работает из-за этого.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была с моими настройками IntelliJ Idea, а конкретно с Maven. Во вкладке Maven->Repositories у меня был указан только локальный источник (а нужен удаленный). Нужно было как-то добавить его через settings.xml. Но это должно просиходить автоматически, это у меня чего-то все пошло не так, поэтому я просто переустановил IntelliJ Idea, НО, перед повторной установкой обязательно нужно еще удалить все связанные с ней конфигурационные файлы из папки пользователя. Потому что не все файлы сами удаляются при удалении Idea. Я пробовал перед этим просто удалить и установить IDE, но это не сработало, а вот после удаления всех связанных с ней файлов вручную все заработало.